# How to mock os.environ using pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I need to mock os.environ in unit tests written using the pytest framework.

Here is a dummy version of the code I want to test, located in `getters.py`:

```
import os

username = os.environ['MY_USER']
password = os.environ['MY_PASS']

def get_data(...):

    access_token = request_access_token(username, password)
    ...
    return data
```

and here is an example of a unit test in `test_getters.py`:

```
import pytest
import src.getters

class TestGetData(object):


    def test_something(self):

        data = src.getters.get_data(...)

        assert ...
```

Test collection fails with the following error:

```
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR tests/test_getters.py - KeyError: 'MY_USER'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================== 1 error in 0.68s ===============================
```

I would like to be able to mock once for the whole test class if possible.

Is there some kind of a decorator I can use? Or some other recommended way of mocking os.environ?

Comment: This works if os.environ['MY_USER'] is accessed from inside of function get_data, but if it's first defined in a global variable, and access that global var from function, this solution does not work. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `monkeypatch.setenv()` of [Monkeypatching](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html):

Docs:

> Modifying environment variables for a test e.g. to test program behavior if an environment variable is missing, or to set multiple values to a known variable. monkeypatch.setenv() and monkeypatch.delenv() can be used for these patches.

Code:

```
import pytest
import src.getters

class TestGetData(object):


    def test_something(self):
        monkeypatch.setenv('MY_USER', 'Nanna')
        monkeypatch.setenv('MY_PASS', 'P@ssw0rd')
        data = src.getters.get_data(...)

        assert ...
```

Comment: Seems like exactly what I need, thanks! Does it work on a class level as well?

Comment: AFAIK Shouldn't be a problem, you [can even set it at the `conftest.py`](https://aalvarez.me/posts/pytest-tricks-for-better-python-tests/)

Comment: This works if os.environ['MY_USER'] is accessed from inside of function `get_data`, but if it's first defined in a global variable, and access that global var from function, this solution does not work. Is there any other solution?